# Chrome Warning for Single-Process

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way (whether via plugins or settings changes) to get rid of the

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --single-process. Stability and security will suffer.

message when I turn on single-process mode?

(*Please*, no lectures on security/stability issues. Thanks!)

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote? It's a bit pointless otherwise....

Comment: I'm guessing someone thought "why in the world would you want to do that?". (not me). Anyhow - I readlly don't think it's possible without editing the sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Chrome has removed Single-process mode completely from their release.

You might still be able to get that option working if you are using the development chrome

Reference:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9052

Comment: Yeah, I'm using version 11.0.671.0, and I know the [exact place](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/ui/browser_init.cc&q=bad_flag%20src/chrome/&exact_package=chromium&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) to edit in Chrome's source code. But I'm wondering if there's any way other than a source code edit that I could remove the warning?